# Setting aria-hidden="false" attribute to "true" for IE7 and IE8 users

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, internet-explorer-7, wai-aria

The responsive navigation on my site uses the aria-hidden="false" attribute. Is there a way I can set it to "true" purely through CSS? If not is there a line of code I can add so it can be set to false for IE7 and IE8 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use jQuery? if so you can do something like :

```
if(/MSIE [78]/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $('* [aria-hidden="false"]').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
}
```